# How to find the lowest using row_number in R?

Tags: r, row-number

CSV file is here: [IMDB movies dataset](https://ufile.io/4qu4o7an).
It contains 180 lines as sample.

How using row_number I will be able to find the lowest row?

I'm able to find longest. How to find shortest?

```r
#longest movie
(longest <- imdb_movies.csv %>%
    filter(row_number(desc(Runtime_in_min)) == 1))
```

Comment: You could use the `which.max` and `which.min` functions.

Comment: What if you remove the `desc` option?

Comment: Are you trying to find the row number of the shortest movie, or just the shortest movie? A more natural `dplyr` way would be something like `data %>% arrange(Runtime_in_min) %>% slice(1)`.

Comment: Or `imdb_movies %>% filter(Runtime_in_min == min(Runtime_in_min))`. This also allows for the possibility that there is more than one movie with the same shortest runtime.

Comment: `top_n(imdb_movies.csv, -1, Runtime_in_min)`

Answer (score 0):

```
movies <- imdb_movies.csv
movies[movies$Runtime_in_min == max(movies$Runtime_in_min),] # Longest
movies[movies$Runtime_in_min == min(movies$Runtime_in_min),] # Shortest
```

Comment: Or just `imdb_movies.csv[which.max(imdb_movies.csv$Runtime_in_min),]`

Comment: 10x r2evans. Works great!

Comment: Or `df[nrow(df), ]`.

Comment: @tmfmnk, that works great if already sorted, I don't know if that is assumed.

Comment: Note that which.max will only ever return a single result.  If there is a tie for the max/min you might get different results depending on which method you use.